# Why should gulp be installed both globally and locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules

I am new to npm and gulp. I am reading this [css-tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) on gulp. In section *Installing Gulp* they installed gulp globally so that it could be used with command line from any location in the computer. In the next section *Creating a Gulp Project* they again installed `gulp` locally.

What I don't understand is if gulp is already installed globally and we can use it from anywhere then why install gulp twice? Why not just put a `gulpfile.js` with other `package.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install `gulp` globally for using simple `gulp` command in your terminal and install `gulp` locally (with `package.json` dependency) in order not to lose the dependency, because you can install your project to any computer, call `npm i` and access `gulp` with `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` without any additional installations

Comment: @user31782 Yes, `npm i` is a short version of  `npm install`

Comment: `npm i` gave me the following error: `H:\C\BRQX\Transports\index1>npm i
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: Also if I install my project to another computer then the node_modules folder will also be copied along. In that folder gulp would already be there so other computer don't need to install gulp globally.

Comment: @user31782 you should add `node_modules` in `.gitignore` file and ever push this folder in your SVN. When anyone clone your project from SVN he just run `npm install` and gets all dependencies from npm. You can read this post to understand why you should do it: https://www.quora.com/Should-I-put-node_modules-in-gitignore

Comment: If I put the node_modules folder in gitignore file then if someone clones the repository he won't download node_modules but he would still download `package.json`file which has already gulp mentioned among many other dependencies in my project. Now I assumes the new developer would still install those dependencies locally because he won't want to install 10 - 50 global dependencies. Now again why he would install gulp both globally and locally?

Comment: @user31782 Installing gulp globally isn't necessary, you just install global dependency to simplify running it. I mean it's more comfortable to run `gulp` or `grunt` or `webpack` or something else than run dependencies like that from `node_modules` with relative path prefixes. So you may not to install global dependencies, it's just for convenience

Comment: Thanks now I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to have installed `gulp` globaly. Just have it locally and put gulp commands in package.json scripts like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "speed-test": "gulp speed-test -v",
    "build-prod": "gulp build-prod",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=spec/support/jasmine.json"
  },
```

Than everyone working on same project can just `npm install` and start running commands without even having gulp globally installed.

- `npm start` will run `gulp`
- `npm run speed-test` will run `gulp speed-test -v`
- `npm run build-prod` will run `gulp build-prod`

And of course add as many commands as you want there. And if someone from team have or wants to have `gulp` globally than they can run `gulp` commands directly from terminal.

Comment: Thanks this seems a useful technique